# Installing lcm-python on ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ubuntu

So I need to install the python version of lcm, which is downloaded from [here](https://github.com/lcm-proj/lcm/releases) , but every time, I end up with this error
[photo of my terminal.1st attempt is with python 2.7.17 and the second is with python 3.6.9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtlAM.png)
Hoping somebody can help me find a way to get this installed. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.